# Autodesk API to PowerBi desktop

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, autodesk-forge, m, autodesk-construction-cloud

I'm trying to connect Autodesk Construction Cloud API directly into my PowerBi desktop.

I tried to get the auth token. But every time I try it throw me error

Can anybody walk me through the steps please?

Comment: can you please edit your answer with the error message?

Comment: See [Connecting To REST APIs With OAuth2 Authentication In Power Query/Power BI](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2021/08/29/connecting-to-rest-apis-with-oauth2-authentication-in-power-query-power-bi/)

Comment: except error message as Augusto suggested, could you also clarify if you are using Forge API (ACC) to access the data and import them to Power BI desktop, or you are actually using ACC Power BI Connector (https://construction.autodesk.com/templates/power-bi-connector/) , if the connector, that will be a product question. In this page, right bottom corner, you can ask help with the online support of this connector. If the former, it means you have some code (programming), then please also try to share some code demo or logic with us to diagnose

Comment: I need to work with this API. https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/overview/introduction/.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @BLACKDRAGON, it sounds your question is just about how to work with ACC API, instead of Power BI specific. If yes, you can find some tutorials at https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/tutorials/getting-started/retrieve-account-and-project-id/, or you could also get started with the this learn forge tutorial https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewhubmodels It is talked about BIM360, but the logic to get account/project/folder/item/version is same with ACC